# executeUpdate() throwing a MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My objective is to add a new row to an existing table which I have created. However, I get the following error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, Last Name, Tel No.)VALUES (2056732, 'Hello', 'World', 3)' at line 1
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2450)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2371)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2355)
>       at AddingNewRow.main(AddingNewRow.java:50)

This is a part of the code. Please let me know if you would need the whole code in order to find out what's wrong.

```
Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the student number: ");
    int studentNO = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the first name: ");
    String fName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the last name: ");
    String lName = in.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the telephone number: ");
    int telNO = in.nextInt();

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //Executing a query
        String sql_query = "INSERT INTO registration (ID, First Name, Last Name, Tel No.) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        System.out.println("Table found");

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_query);
        ps.setInt(1, studentNO); 
        ps.setString(2, fName);
        ps.setString(3, lName);
        ps.setInt(4, telNO);
        System.out.println("Values added");

        ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Values updated");

    }
```

> This is the output I get when I run the program
>
> Enter the student number: 1234567
>
> Enter the first name: Hello
>
> Enter the last name: World
>
> Enter the telephone number: 123321
>
> Connected
>
> Table found
>
> Values added
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException...

I understand that this may just be en extremely foolish question, but I just started on working with databases and couldn't figure out whats wrong with the code even after going through most of the other similar questions posted here.

If anyone can show me what's wrong, I would be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be worried about column names with spaces in....

Comment: Are you sure the column has a full stop ? `Tel No.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO registration (`ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Tel No.`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

column name with `backticks`.

Comment: As singhakash says, using backticks allows characters such as space to be used in an SQL query.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did work!
Can you explain what was wrong earlier and why your method worked? I'm still new to programming and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the line

```
String sql_query = "INSERT INTO registration (ID, First Name, Last Name, Tel No.) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

with

```
String sql_query = "INSERT INTO registration (`ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Tel No.`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Also if I were you, I would try to avoid special characters and spaces in table and field names as those are the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I really appreciate your tip. I will keep that in mind for the next time I'm working with databases.

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by you using `setString` to set the student ID number. That will tell the prepared statement it should be a String, not an Integer. Also, you may need to put back ticks around the `Tel No.` field.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was testing different things out with the code just to find out where the error was. It was initially set to setInt, and didn't work either. I fixed that particular error. Thanks for pointing it out.